# Using RVM with GVim (Cream): rvm command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, ubuntu, vim, rvm

I am trying to move to GVim(cream) as my primary editor on Ubuntu. I am using the wonderful rails.vim, however I also am using RVM.

Rvm works fine when doing things in a shell, and the ruby version I would like to use in rails.vim is the version set as default (but not the system version).

When I try to run things like

```
:Rgenerate migration migration_name
```

I get:

```
...
Missing Rails 2.3.8 gem.
...
```

If I try:

```
:!rvm use default
```

I get:

```
/bin/bash: rvm: command not found
```

Obviously cream/gvim is not using my .bashrc. What can I do to remedy this and get it working? Thanks.

Comment: Same issue also present in gvim and only occurs when I use the application menu/Gnome Do to launch the application.

If launch gvim from the shell then rvm works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running cream from the command line, if this solves the issue you can point your menu item to a script that opens cream in the context of a bash prompt.

Comment: This sounds the most promising. Any suggestions on how to go about doing this? Pointing me towards the right search terms so I can learn myself would be appreciated.

Comment: Try writing a file that contains `cream &` and save as `whatever.sh`, then try running that script.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are sourcing the rvm scripts in your .zshrc file. MacVim does not source the .zshrc file, but will source the .zshenv file.

Add following line to your .vimrc file.

```
set shell=/bin/sh
```

Comment: NB this is an answer to a Mac-specific problem, and the questioner is using Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

You probably have used .bash_profile to add RVM stuff to your bash environment. Alas, ~/.bash_profile won't normally be read by X startup scripts, as stated in [Ubuntu Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Session-wide%20environment%20variables)

Use .profile or .bashrc. The .profile is only sourced by bash if .bash_profile is not there. I would use .bashrc.

Comment: Oh, and don't forget to restart the X session after making changes.

Comment: Thanks. However, I actual already used .bashrc to add rvm. I was mistaken when I said bash profile above.

Comment: Thanks, this worked great.  I'm on a clean install an haven't touched these files yet, so I assume RVM installed the RVM scripts line to my .bash_profile by default.  Copying that line to the .bashrc fixed it next time I launched a new bash shell.

Answer (score 0):

rvm is a bash function, which changes bash environment. Seems like it is not supposed to be run from inside vim. You can't change the environment of an already-running program.

Comment: Okay, so it should like What I need to do is launch it from the correct bash profile, perhaps like thomasfedb suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Try `rvm gem list` to make sure the rails gem is actually installed. `rails (2.3.8)` should be listed. If its not run `rvm gem install rails`.

I'm a vim user, and rvm + rails.vim works fine for me. Including your `:Rgenerate` example.

Comment: RVM is installed, gvim just is not loading is the scope of the bash profile.

Answer (score 0):

rvm is set on a per shell basis, so if you launch a new window or a new tab and you are using something other than your default interpreter and gemset you need to first

`rvm gemset use my_rails238_gemset`

and then

`vim myshiz`

Comment: This is pretty much what I have been doing. Launching gvim from the terminal results in the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your ~/.bashrc:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

And make sure it comes before `[ -z "$PS1" ] && return` which stops sourcing the rest of the file if bash is not interactive.

And then add this to your ~/.profile:

```
export BASH_ENV=$HOME/.bashrc
```

With this line bash will now source $HOME/.bashrc when it is running non-interactively too.
Both GVim and shell scripts that you execute by double clicking should use RVM now.

Note: Only `:!` (ex: `:!ruby`, `:!echo`) commands will use RVM as commands like `:ruby` and `:echo` do not run bash and therefore do not source ~/.bashrc.

Answer (score 0):

Running gvim from the command line doesn't work for me (in the sense that it's not acceptable). 
When I am using a GUI application, I want to use it like a GUI, without a useless shell lingering in the background.

The '`set shell=`' trick that works for Mac users doesn't work for me. Like you, I am using Ubuntu. Even setting the shell to `/bin/bash` doesn't do it.

The only thing I've gotten to work is this. First of all, install [rvm.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rvm) in addition to [rails.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails).

Then, when you open gvim/cream, navigate to your project's root folder then type

```
:Rvm
```

This will cause rvm.vim to read your `.ruby-version` (or `.rvmrc`) file and initialize itself properly.

At this point,

```
:Rake
:Rgenerate
```

...and other rails.vim commands should work just fine.

Note that you can also pass arguments to `:Rvm` just as you would when running `rvm` from the shell.

Comment: I am also using GVim on Ubuntu and _rvm.vim_ plugin was only way to get _rails.vim_ working. A tip: put `:autocmd VimEnter * Rvm` into your .vimrc so you don't have to rung :Rvm all the time manually